# list of prime factors

Tags: java, primes, prime-factoring

I'm new to programming and Stack-overflow but I'm trying to create a list of prime factors from a number but it is returning more than one list and I don't know why. For example when I enter 10, it returns [2,5] and [2,5,5] instead of just [2,5]. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong?

```
public class Solution {
    ArrayList<Integer> primelist = new ArrayList<>();

    ArrayList<Integer> findPrime(int num) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                primelist.add(i);
                num = num / i;
                if (num == 1) { break;}
                findPrime(num);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(primelist);
        return primelist;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        sol.findPrime(30);//[2, 3, 5],[2, 3, 5, 5], [2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5],[2, 3, 5, 5, 3, 5, 5]
        sol.findPrime(10);//[2, 5],[2, 5, 5]
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect it to print only once?

Comment: Since the method is recursive it gets called more than once. Each invocation prints another line.

Comment: You're making a recursive call there in your if block.

Comment: Why are you looping *and* recursing? Make up your mind.

Comment: @EJP  "I'm new to programming and Stack-overflow..."   No need to be rude.

Comment: I consider it (a) a reasonable question and (b) not rudely expressed. I also don't consider that you've actually answered it.

Comment: @EJP's "rude" (allegedly) comment, paraphrased more gently but **much less succinctly**: By recursively calling `findPirme` inside the loop in `findPrime`, you are finding not only the prime factors of your original number, but prime factors of those prime factors, and prime factors of prime factors of those prime factors,  and prime factors of prime factors of prime factors of prime factors, etc.  Either the loop **alone** or the recursion **alone** should be sufficient to do the job. Why did you think it necessary to do both?

Comment: @KevinAnderson Thank you for the response. I was not understanding loops correctly and thought that I have to recursively call the function in order for it to loop on the new num. Now I understand EJP 's comment that I could have done this with either recursion or using a loop but it makes no sense to mix the two. thank you

Comment: @ken24ny would you mind accepting my answer if its correct? :)

Answer (score 0):

Im guessing you try to achieve *the Sieve of Eratosthenes*.

this works:

```
   @Test
    public void numbers() {

        class Solution {

            List<Integer> sieveOfEratosthenes(int n) {
                boolean prime[] = new boolean[n + 1];
                Arrays.fill(prime, true);
                for (int p = 2; p * p <= n; p++) {
                    if (prime[p]) {
                        for (int i = p * 2; i <= n; i += p) {
                            prime[i] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                List<Integer> primeNumbers = new LinkedList<>();
                for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
                    if (prime[i]) {
                        primeNumbers.add(i);
                    }
                }
                return primeNumbers;
            }
        }
        //test it..
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        System.out.println(sol.sieveOfEratosthenes(10));
        System.out.println(sol.sieveOfEratosthenes(100));

    }
```

... which yields correct results:

```
[2, 3, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97]
```

i borrowed this code [from this article](http://www.baeldung.com/java-generate-prime-numbers), an detailed explanation of the steps of the algorithm can be found there.